# Makeclothes: singular matrix in corner weight

Tags: makehuman

We're using the Makeclothes module in Blender to create clothes and we face a problem: while exporting, we get a small box with the error message: "singular matrix in corner weight".
After looking at the Python code, I find that the full error message was printed in the console. I get it, get the number of the vertex producing the error and we're able to select it.
Right, but what does this error means and how can we correct that?

Note: we delete the vertex, create it again and now that's OK. But the question remains: what does it means??

Comment: can you add a link to this Makeclothes addon you are using?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/TeoTwawki/makehuman/blob/master/blendertools/makeclothes/makeclothes.py  The error display is generated on line 555. But there's no real explanation (which is the case with other errors)